# Primary user of Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

```
<?php
class Blog extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        echo 'Hello World!';
    }
}
?>
```

I read the user guide carefully and try to run the code.first i create code in notepad which are above and then save it to the application/controller.but it give the error

```
A Database Error Occurred

Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.

Filename: D:\xampp\htdocs\ci_intro\system\database\DB_driver.php

Line Number: 124
```

which is to be made change to run this code successfully.please anyone can help me.i am a primary user of codeigniter.so i don't understand the error.

Comment: please check the database.php file in config folder and then check is there database name is written in that file or not?

Answer (score 1):

Seems that you are trying to connect to database. If that is the case check your settings in config/database.php
If you don't want to connect to database, check your config/autoload.php and make sure that you are not autoloading the database library.
http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/connecting.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use database then you should fill out the config/database.php with the mysql db info. (I see you are using xampp so DB Driver would be mysql I suppose)

Lets say we have following database information: databaseName, databaseUser and databasePassword;

Soo the database.php would be filled out like this:

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['default']['username'] = 'databaseUser';
$db['default']['password'] = 'databasePassword';
$db['default']['database'] = 'databaseName';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
```

Answer (score 0):

**you wrote a right code.** this error occur when you try to connect to your database with wrong config. to change your configuration go to `application > config` folder and open `database.php` file.

in that you see some config like this.

```
$active_group = 'default';
$active_record = TRUE;

$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['default']['username'] = 'username';
$db['default']['password'] = 'password';
$db['default']['database'] = 'databaseName';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

before these configs they completely described and say how you can use them. read them and set your config.

[this reference](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/configuration.html) is useful to understand how you can config your database. if you config your database you can run your code without any problem.